# Changing from Python 2 to 3

Tags: python

So I am brand new to python. I am following tutorials on it but it appears the tutorial i am using is python 2. I figured I would try to change the code to python 3. I am getting errors on the import praw. When I ran this in python 2 no problems but now after the changes and trying to run in python 3 it says praw module doesn't exist. Python 2.7 found it. I just tried upgrading it. What am I missing? here's my code:

Python:

```
import praw
import config
import time

example_list = ["test", "hello","123", 0]
example_list.append(32.10)
print(example_list)

def bot_login():
    print("Logging in...")
    r = praw.Reddit(username = config.username,
            password = config.password,
            client_id = config.client_id,
            client_secret = config.client_secret,
            user_agent = "i_am_learning_bot's dog comment responder v.01")
    print("logged in!")

    return r

def run_bot(r):
    print("Obtaining 25 comments...")
    for comment in r.subreddit('test').comments(limit=25):
        if "dog" in comment.body:
            print("String with \"dog\" found in comment " + comment.id)
            comment.reply("Ohh dogs? I also love dags! [Here](http://i.imgur.com/LLgRKeq.jpg) is an image of one.)")
            print ("Replied to comment" + comment.id)
    print("Sleeping for 10 seconds...")
    #sleep for 10 seconds...
    time.sleep(10)

#r = bot_login()
#while True:
#    run_bot(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is probably fine, but `pip` modules aren't shared between Python versions. If you have Python 2 *and* Python 3 installed, then you usually need to use `pip3` to install packages for Python 3. Just `pip` will install Python 2 packages.

This means that you need to execute the following command in your terminal:

```
pip3 install praw
```

Answer (score 0):

The python packages are associated with python versions. The `praw` package is only installed for Python 2 but **NOT** for Python 3.

Depending on how you installed your python 3, you will need to install the `praw` package. For example, do `pip3 install praw`, `conda install praw`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for smt like:

```
pip3 install praw
```

Because python3.x and 2.x do not share same packages.. Good luck bro!